# Nusselt number equations for external flow over a single finned tube heat exchanger

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer, hvac, convection, heat

I am designing a heat exchanger that will utilize a singular finned tube of around 2" diameter with 4 fins per inch that are 3/4" tall and .03" thick. I am looking at finding the Nusselt number for the air side of the heat exchanger. The air is moving over the heat exchanger at .4 m/s. The Reynolds number is calculated to be around ~712. I am posting here because I am struggling to find an appropriate Nusselt number relation for a singular finned tube. All the equations I am finding relate to finned tube banks.

The purpose of this heat exchanger is to provide heat to a small underground room that is being designed for a Senior engineering project.

Comment: You would probably be better off finding effectiveness NTU curves or a fin equation.  In not sure there would be a meaningful Nu number formula for such a complex geometry.

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to extrapolate trends versus number of tubes. The extrapolation may not be linear. An alternate approach that may be more insightful is to determine the Nusselt number for a blank tube, extract the heat transfer coefficient for the blank tube system, and then apply the approach using effectiveness expressions for a single-tube with fins.

$$\dot{q} = h\left(A_o + N_f\ \eta_f\ A_f\right)\Delta T$$

You do not say whether the system has longitudinal fins with air flow down the tube or radial fins with air flow over the tube. In the former case, finding an average after neglecting the starting end should suffice. In the latter case, the Nusselt number for the blank tube will be dependent on radial position over the tube. Take the lowest and highest to see the extremes in predicted heat flow.